# Warning which says that repository has not been configured for replication

Tags: warnings, artifactory, replication

I'm checking the replication configuration of a repository which was configured to be replicated but I'm getting the warning that you can see in the image below:
[image]

I don't know what does that means and why it does show up if the replication was properly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described behavior appears to be related to a known issue which is documented in JFrog JIRA project as "UI doesn't reflect actual status of Enable Event Replication Checkbox"([RTFACT-26807](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-26807))

The above has been fixed in Artifactory v7.36.